# How to substitute C:\Users\username\AppData with C:\%USERPROFILE% in batch

Tags: firefox, batch-file

I am very new to scripting and I am having difficulties with a script that I am working on. I am trying to make it so that I can push this script over the network to all computers so that it can modify a line in the about:config file within firefox. My question is why does this script not run if I replace C:\Users\marc.tucciarone\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\w6i1jk03.default 
with 
C:\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\w6i1jk03.default

Thanks, sorry for the noob question scripting is not my best skill...

```
@ECHO OFF
set "var=user_pref("security.mixed_content.block_active_content", false);"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd C:\Users\marc.tucciarone\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\w6i1jk03.default

findstr /m "security.mixed_content.block_active_content" prefs.js

if %errorlevel%==0 (

echo Found! 

pause

exit

) else (

cd C:\Users\marc.tucciarone\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\w6i1jk03.default

echo !var! >> prefs.js


if errorlevel 1 echo Unsuccessful
echo Addin string 

pause


)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%userprofile% already includes the drive letter. So you don't have to write

```
C:\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\w6i1jk03.default
```

but only

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\w6i1jk03.default
```

Are you aware of the systemvariable `%appdata%`?

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\w6i1jk03.default
```

is a bit shorter  ;-)

Comment: That worked ! thanks so much. I didnt realize that the drive letter was already included.